# where is the option "build path" for jar in eclipse indigo?

Tags: eclipse

I put one new jar file in the dir libs (together android jar), but...i need to build also the path.
Where is the option "build path"? Usually it was enough the right click on the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the project. Or go to Eclipse Preferences, then search for Build Path.

Comment: yea...quite weird...usually it was enough right click on the directory libs (on juno), with indigo on the project (i did not see it). Thanks.